# Most efficient and shortest way to combine similar long jQuery functions

Tags: jquery

I have these 3 similar separate functions:

```
$("a").click(function () {
        $(this).slideUp();

/* additional long identical code */
});

$("b").click(function () {
        $(this).css("color", "blue");
/* additional long identical code */
});

$("c").click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
/* additional long identical code */
});
```

They all have additional long identical code.
I am wondering if there is any other shorter and more efficient way to combine them. This is what I did:

```
$("a, b, c").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is("a")) {
        $(this).slideUp();
    }

    else if ($(this).is("b")) {
        $(this).css("color", "blue");
    }

    else if ($(this).is("c")) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
/* additional long identical code */
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a3ryaud4/

Comment: Give them a class and use `$(".classname").on("click",function() { if (this.id=="a")...`

Comment: Use class instead of inline CSS to `b` element

Comment: or you can use `switch` too instead of `if-else`. But the way you came up with in the 2nd part of code seems good..

Comment: Consider keeping the click handler definitions separate as you have them already, and simply make a function call for the long identical code. That may be a more manageable approach in general for handling events and then executing identical code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something

```
$("a, b, c").click(function () {
    $e = $(this);
    ($e.is("a")?$e.slideUp():$e.is("b")?$e.css("color", "blue"):$e.hide());
});
```

But my way is shortening the code always is not a good practice, you should maintain `modularity` and so establish a tradeoff between readablility and size.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like user mplungjan suggested but using Javascript switch method.

Something like this:

```
$(".classname").on("click",function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    switch (id) {
      case "a":
        console.log("a clicked");
        break;
      case "b":
        console.log("b clicked");
        break;

      ...

      default:
        console.log(id + " clicked");
    }

}
```

Switch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: Missed quote of the `id`, 2nd line and I guess OP is not using IDs, those are  elements

Comment: Thanks Tushar, this is only example code (pseudo) :D